# Google sites, iframe, parsing id

Tags: javascript

I registred a page on sites.google.com.
https://sites.google.com/site/redirre4/?id=3434343434
I selected an iframe widjet, feel in my link

> `http://92.63.106.195/test`
>
> index.html

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function getUrlVars() {
     var vars = {};
     var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(m,key,value) {
          vars[key] = value;
     });
     return vars;
}
var id = getUrlVars()["id"];
var url = 'http://ya.ru/?flowid=545&code=ixynrgjgfdhnurl&id=';

       alert (url + id);
    top.location.href = (url + id);

 </script>
</head>

</html>
```

But I have a problem, a function can't parse an id. What's wrong with it?

Comment: which is the value returned by window.location.href ?

Comment: It is https://sites.google.com/site/redirre4/?id=3434343434 Maybe)

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to violate the Same Origin Policy

Comment: sure about it? I asked because I don't know if the script is executed inside an iframe. In any case the code is right, see http://jsfiddle.net/wJ83Z/.